# Simulate/Generate a SocketTimeoutException in a servlet

Tags: java, soap, tdd, agile

I'm working a web project that use:
 - Java
 - Jetty
 - [Fitnesse tool](http://fitnesse.org/)
 - etc..

I have a difficulty to simulate/generate a SocketTimeoutException, more info below:

---

**The use-case-simplified:**
I wrote a API that make calls to a host(***WebServer***).
In the source-code if I receive a [RemoteException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html) and is a **SocketTimeoutException**, I need to retry in some other host.

All is working nice!

**How we test:**
Is a TDD project so we have a bunch of UT. And for a 'real' test we use the tool mentioned above. (Fitnesse)

**The '*problem*':**
I have to simulate many problems that could occur in the Server. For that I wrote a simple servlet that simulate my WebServer.
But for this use-case I need to simulate a SocketTimeoutException in my simulator. I was thinking in put a sleep in the simulator, but I think this could cause a client request timeout.

---

If someone have any idea or a good tip will be very nice to know!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Set the socket read timeout programmatically to 1 milliseconds and you will always get a java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

HTH

Comment: Great tip especially when you try to test if a Timeout setting works from a Client-perspective. e.g. when sending email and you connect to an SMTP server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on your question. Can you just try:

`throw new SocketTimeoutException();`

Comment: My API access a WebServer, I'm writing a simulator for this webserver. If I throw a exception in the simulator I'll not receive this exception in my client. Is a client of a webservice. This simulator is to be used in the tool fitnesse.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is based on the "keep alive" between sockets (what is the likely to cause the socket to timeout), you may have to make the socket connection across two computers and then remove the cable between them (or the connection to a switch).  The the "keep alive" timeout occurs, hopefully you will get a SocketTimeoutException.

Depending upon the setting for the "keep alive" (You might be able to set this through socket options), it may take minutes to hours (NT was approximately 5 hour for a keep alive to time out, but it was setable in the registry).

If that does not give you the expected exception, I'm not sure what conditions need to occur to cause a timeout.

Might what to look at these links to see if they are any help.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t363525-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out.html

http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/29249/SocketTimeoutException-Read-timed-out